# Trouble shooting Django form/view/template and how they all work together

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to learn Django from the book and I read most of it and am now trying to write a webapp of my own. I just really can't figure out how they all interact and how they aren't fitting together.

---

My urls.py file reads like this...

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from users.views import homepageview, submitted, referral_create

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^$', homepageview),
(r'^submitted/$', referral_create),
```

the views.py file looks like this...

```
  # Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django import forms
from datreferral.users.forms import ReferralCode

def homepageview(request):
    now = 'your damn referral code'
    return render_to_response('datreferraltemplate.html', {'now': now})

def referral_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReferralCode(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_code = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(contact_details, args=(new_contact.pk,)))
    else:
        form = ReferralCode()
```

The form.py file looks like

```
from django import forms

class ReferralCode(forms.Form):
    referralcode = forms.CharField()
```

and the template looks like this...

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Enter your referral codes!
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Enter your code</h1>

    {% if errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" value="{{ referralcode }}"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Hopefully that's enough info.

I am looking for two things. First off, when I try to view the page after submitting the form i get no where because I assume that the "if request.method == 'POST':" is not triggering. Obviously its something pretty obvious but I'm in one of those modes where I can find the bug for the life of me.

The second question I have is basically is plea for help. somehow after reading through those chapters multiple times I can't seem to nail down how all of the pieces interact with each other. I know that the template and the urls.py and the views.py interact and I get (I think) but I can't really grasp how the database and forms interact with each other and with the views/templates. like say I just wanted to a simple form where whatever the use inputted is written into the database... How would you do that? I'm using postgres if that matters.

Note: the form and the  in the template is a modified version of code i found on here and tried to manipulate to meet my needs but failed so don't be overly thrown off if that doesn't make sense I wasn't able to mess with that part that much yet because of these problems.

As I'm new to web development I really appreciate any one willing to help me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't return anything in you else clause. A views must **always** return a response,  which can be pretty much anything, but in most cases you will return a instance of a (sub)-class of `HttpResponse` (I really like the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut). It is a good idea to have a default return at the bottom of you view, add some early returns for "special" responses and otherwise let the execution reach the default return - this way you never have the case where you return nothing.
2. You have to use a Model to save data (have you work through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models)?). Usually the excution model is the following:

   1. you app gets a request and the urls.py is searched for a view that should be called
   2. the request is passed through the [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/)
   3. you view is called and "does" something. I.e. it fetches data from the database (again using a model) or stores something in the db (or saves a uploaded file, sends a mail, etc. - aview can really do anything)
   4. you view returns "something"
   5. the returned "something" is passed through the middleware and will eventually be tranformed in a stream of data that is passed to the browser

Thats it. This is a bit simplified but it pretty much covers all important parts.

Comment: okay wow. I'll have to look everything over figure out what went wrong when I was reading the book. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are quite a few things wrong here.

First is that your form is being rendered by the base view, `homepageview`, and is submitting back to that same URL. However the form processing logic is in a separate view, which isn't being called. Either change the `action` parameter of the form to point to the other URL or - better - move all the logic into the same view.

Secondly, your form processing view isn't returning a response or rendering a template. That's an error in Django, and if you had managed to call that view you would see an exception.

Thirdly, I find it hard to believe you've read the entire Django book and not seen anything about models or databases. You've got no indication here that you've set up any models, but without them Django won't write anything to a database. You'll need to do that, then change your form into a ModelForm subclass, after which you can call `form.save()` successfully.

Comment: whoa. alright. To be honest i read them all once and them re read chapters as needed. I can't honest claim the cover to cover status.</ br>

and I never remember reading anything about this subclass Modelform. Is that in the book? I'll have to look it over but I completely missed that. </br>

also I did set up models but like I said I'm overly confused on how they interact with everything and didn't think that they effected this. So i didnt include them. </br>